# Fetching data from coredata in swift

Tags: swift

I have two entities in my core data “Product” and “Images”.There is a one-To-Many relationship between product and image. I am able to store numbers of images gallery to a product.

```
@IBAction func fetchImageFromLibrary(_ sender: UIButton) {
  var config = YPImagePickerConfiguration()
         config.library.maxNumberOfItems = 15
         let picker = YPImagePicker(configuration: config)

         picker.didFinishPicking { [unowned picker] items, cancelled in
             for item in items {
                 switch item {
                 case .photo(let photo):
                    self.executeCoredata(tempImage: photo.image)

                     self.tableView.reloadData()
                 case .video(let video):
                     print(video)
                 }
             }
             picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
         }
         present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}



func executeCoredata(tempImage: UIImage) {

    let moc = CoredataStack.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext

             guard let imageData = tempImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) else {
                                  // handle failed conversion
                                  print("jpg error")
                                  return
                              }


            let coreProduct = Product(context: moc)
            coreProduct.id = Int32(randomNumber())
            coreProduct.name = randomString(length: 6)
            let imageToStore = coreProduct.image?.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableSet

            let coreImage = Images(context: moc)
            coreImage.image = imageData
            coreImage.name = randomString(length: 5)
            imageToStore.add(coreImage)

    let randomInt = Int.random(in: 1...2)

    if randomInt == 1{
        coreImage.isUploading = true
    }
    if randomInt == 2{
        coreImage.isUploading = false

    }

            coreProduct.image = imageToStore.copy() as? NSSet


            CoredataStack.shared.saveContext()
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            checkDataAvailibility()
        }


    And showing the product in my table view like: -

   func checkDataAvailibility() {
   let request: NSFetchRequest<Product>  = Product.fetchRequest()
   let sortByName = NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)
          let sortDescriptors =  [sortByName]

          request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
    let moc = CoredataStack.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
       do {
           let imageCount = try moc.count(for: request)

           if imageCount > 0{
               productList = try moc.fetch(request)

           }

       }catch {
                     fatalError("Error in counting home record")
                 }

   DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.tableView.reloadData()
   }

   }


   //MARK: Tableview Datasource
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    print(productList.count)
    return productList.count

}

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? productCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    cell.productId.text = String(productList[indexPath.row].id)
    cell.productName.text = productList[indexPath.row].name

    let nsarr = productList[indexPath.row].image!.allObjects as NSArray

    for item in nsarr as! [Images]{

        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: item.image!)
        cell.imageName.text = item.name
        if item.isUploading == true{
            cell.isUploading.text = "isUploading"
        }
        else{
             cell.isUploading.text = "Uploaded"
        }

        print("upload status: \(item.isUploading)")

    }


    return cell

}
```

My Question is - I want to show data in the table view according to the image status.Means, if the status is uploading, then the image should be shown.How to do this?